# Angular 6 Subject next method not triggering in child component

Tags: angular

I am having an issue where a child component is not subscribing to a Subject in my service. I have a list these task components and the first two initialized in the service display correctly. I then have a button that navigates to a form which calls the addTask() method in the service. I know this form and method is working correctly since the tasks array is being updated by my form and I can see this with my console.log statement. However, when I navigate back I see only the original two tasks and I see in the console my components ngOnInit function is never triggered. I call the addTask method on the form's submission. The service is provided in the appmodule and my folder structure is below:

```
work-folder:
 edit-task-folder (form to add new task)
 wi-list-folder (component to list tasks. No being updated here)
 workitemservice.ts
```

**Service**

```
export class WorkItemService {
tasksChanged = new Subject<Task[]>();

private tasks: Task[] = [
  new Task(
    'example title',
    'this is the task desciption',
    4 
  ),
  new Task(
    'example title2',
    'this is the task desciption2',
    4 
  )
];

addTask(task: Task) {
  this.tasks.push(task);
  this.tasksChanged.next(this.tasks.slice());
  console.log('tasks in service', this.tasks.slice());
}
getTasks(){
  console.log('getTasks() returns: ', this.tasks);
  return this.tasks.slice();
}
```

**Here is my component file:**

```
subscription: Subscription;
  tasks: Task[];

  constructor(private workItemService: WorkItemService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.workItemService.tasksChanged
      .subscribe(
        (tasks: Task[]) => {
          this.tasks = tasks;
          console.log('tasks in subscription', this.tasks)
        }
      );
    this.tasks = this.workItemService.getTasks();
  }
```

Thank you for any help!

**Update:**

The issue was fixed by removing the service as a provider in the component file>

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz or a minimal plunker

Comment: It seems to be working here.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-749wz

Comment: That's a good idea I'm trying to set it up on stackblitz now. Your link is broken for me though.

Comment: Make sure the service is within the module component and not globally

Comment: updated link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-749wzi

Comment: Yes that looks good, I think the problem comes from routing to the form for user input then back to the page with the list of tasks. I included a link to the github project so the scope is easier to see. https://github.com/fishjaam/task-manager